# How to remove frames or isolate a segment of frames from timeline (no keyframes ... former .ABC file)

Tags: animation

I have a Transformer animation I purchased off CGTrader. It came as an .ABC file. I imported the .ABC file into Blender. The existing frame range is -72 to 998. I want to isolate frames -30 to 195 and save as a new file (reset as frames 1-225) that I can then bring into another Blender project I’m working on (compositing the 3d animation into live action footage…my live action plate has frames 1-225).

While I can choose “allow negative frames” in “Preferences”, and can click the clock button to use preview range, that only impacts playback. I can’t change the frame start in “Scene” settings as it automatically changes to 0 if I try to put in -30 (although it stays at -72 as long as I don’t touch it).

Because this was an imported ABC file, there are no key frames. Thus, the standard selecting keyframes and deleting them doesn’t work.

I read somewhere that you can convert the scene to a strip and edit it that way (choosing the frame range I want to cut out), but I haven’t been able to figure out how to do that. I’ve attached a screenshot of what I’m looking at.
[image: Screenshot of what I'm looking at]
Thank you in advance for any tips or help that anyone can provide.

Comment: I think the simplest option would be to offset your alembic within positive frame numbers. Do you have that option when importing the alembic file (in the sidebar while browsing for the abc file in Blender). Otherwise I think you have that option on the object itself, in the modifiers tab. But you'll need to make that change on every object. You can do its once and then synchronise the modifiers settings. But check the import option first, it will be simpler. We'll see how it goes from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I don't think these are viable options without a massive amount of work. When I first imported the alembic file, I saved it as a .blend and also I had to go back through and re-assign new materials to all the objects in the model as they did not import correctly. There are hundreds of individual objects in this model. It took me several days. This would also mean that I would have to do the same thiing with the modifiers that  you mention.

I wish there was just an easy way to trim off frames.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if you modify the Offset value on one object, it seems to propagate to all other objects of the same alembic file:

[image]

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything..

Wondering if there's any way to use the VSE to do this. Soimeone here said you can load your scene as a scene strip and cut out frames you don't want. But I've been unable to successfully get this into the VSE.

https://blenderartists.org/t/remove-frames/508193/5

Comment: That's for rendering, you are just offsetting where your scene will be rendered in the final video editing, you are not actually offsetting anything in the scene.

Comment: Using the frame offset should work, have you tried setting it to 31 ? Could you provide an example scene with the issue ?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't do anything. I chose one of the objects in the model (I chose "bone left femur"), go to "Modifier Properties", click "Add Modifier", chose "MeshSequenceCache", and chose the original ABC file for the file path and the bone left femur for the object path. I then set Frame Offset to 31. It had zero impact on anything, and the setting didn't propagate through any other parts of the model either.

Comment: OK looks like I solved the issue now. If I go the "Main Father controller" which is the top in the hierarchy of all the objects, then choose "add object constraint" and "Transform Cache" and the file path as the original ABC file, then do the frame offset, it now works! Thank you for your help!